# Homework- Sort of :/ Double - string prolem

Tags: c#, string

I got this homework assignment, cant figure it out.
I need to ask the user how many town names he wants to enter. For example 5.
Then, he enters the 5 town names.
Afterwards, we need to find the average length of the names and show him the names which have less letters than the average length. Thanks for your shared time :)
My code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    int n;
    Console.WriteLine("How many town names would you like to enter:");
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    string[] TownNames = new string[n];
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} town names:", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter number {0}: ", i + 1);
        TownNames[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

static void Average(double[] TownNames, int n)
{

}
```

Comment: In which language did you develop this code? Please add a suitable tag. You can do that by click on link 'edit' underneath your post.

Comment: reporter is right, you need to tag the question with the language you are using before people can help

Comment: Where are you stuck?  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Why do you expect the names of your towns to be `double`s?

Comment: please add a language tag -I'm guessing this is C#-,and please add spaces before your `static void Main(string[] args) {` to add it to the code area. And why are you using `Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine())` , `Console.ReadLine()` should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. What you have in your main method is an array that you populate with the name of the towns the user inputs. I would separate these two criteria into separate methods:

```
int FindAverage(string[] towns);
IEnumerable<string> FilterShortNamedTowns(string[] towns, int average);
```

The average should be pretty easy. You just need to calculate the average based on the [Length property exposed by the string class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx). This property keeps track of how many characters are in the string.

```
private static int FindAverage(string[] towns)
{
   int totalLength = 0;
   foreach(var town in towns)
      totalLength += town.Length;

   return totalLength / towns.Length;

   // This can be shortened to the following use LINQ but the above shows the algorithm better.
   // return towns.Select(town => town.Length).Average();
}
```

The second method should just cycle through the collection again and return only the towns where the Length < average.

```
private static IEnumerable<string> FilterShortNamedTowns(string[] towns, int average)
{
   return towns.Where(town => town.Length < average);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To find the average length of the names you have to sum up the length of all names. then divide it by number of names.

```
int n;
Console.WriteLine("How many town names would you like to enter:");
n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
string[] TownNames = new string[n];
Console.Clear();

int totalLength = 0; // holds total length of names
Console.WriteLine("Enter {0} town names:", n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter number {0}: ", i + 1);
    TownNames[i] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

    totalLength += TownNames[i].Length; // add the name length to total
}

int average = totalLength/n; // calculate average

Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("town names lower than average length:");

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (TownNames[i].Length < average) // print values when the length name is less than average.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Town {0} : {1}", i + 1, TownNames[i]);
    }
}


Console.ReadKey(true);
```